# Active Record - Charting how many people in a group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick in my RoR app and I'm trying to create a pie chart that displays all the `People` that are in each `Group`. My Group and Person model are both HABTM. Right now the chart is working and only displaying number of groups(screenshot and code below) if someone knows how to grab the number of people in each group using active record I'd love it!

here is my code

```
<%= pie_chart Group.group(:name).count %>
```

Here is a screenshot

[image]

here is my Schema

```
  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "phone_number"
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
t.boolean  "subscribed",   default: true, null: false
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "zip"
t.string   "country"
 end

 create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

 create_table "groups_people", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "group_id",  null: false
t.integer "person_id", null: false
end
```

here is the person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :deliveries
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

here is group model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :people
 has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= pie_chart Group.includes(:people).all.map {|g| [g.name, g.people.size] }.to_h %>
```

By the way, it will better to move this logic into model body.

Comment: I think you're on the right track but I get this error

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: near "group": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, group AS group FROM "people" GROUP BY "group"

Comment: update please your question with models and schema code and let me know)

Comment: Now getting uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::People